# Radio buttons not working correctly in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, radio-button, vue.js

I have generated multiple radio button groups in a page.Each group consists of two items - *yes* and *no*

```
<div v-if="row.answer_input_type === 'Radio Button'">
                            <template v-for="answer in answers" >
                                <template v-if="answer.AnswerTypeID === row.answer_type_id">
                                   <template v-for="answerdesc in answer.AnswerDescription">
                                       <p>{{answerdesc.AnswerMasterID}}</p>
                                       <input type="radio" v-bind:value="answerdesc.AnswerMasterID" v-bind:name="row.question_id" v-bind:id="answerdesc.AnswerMasterID" v-bind:disabled="row.is_enabled == 1 ? false : true" v-on:click="rdoClick(row.question_id, answerdesc.AnswerMasterID)" v-model="answer.selected_option" />
                                       <label v-bind:for="answerdesc.AnswerMasterID">{{answerdesc.AnswerDescription}}</label>
                                   </template>
                                </template>
                             </template>
                        </div>
```

but whenever the selection is changed in a radio button group, the same is reflected in all the other radio button groups. That is if I select yes in one group in all the other group yes is selected. But the v-model is different for each. How to solve/correct this? thanks

Comment: please post your 'answers' object.

Comment: also check that `row.question_id` is different for each answer group

Comment: @RoyJ row.question is different for each one

Comment: What happens if you remove the `v-on:click`? You shouldn't need that with `v-model`

Comment: @RoyJ On click I am sending some parameters to  method and making some changes to some json data

Comment: @RoyJ there are multiple codes like the one I mentioned in my quesion , each for a different type of control.

Comment: We're going to need to see a minimal amount of your data that exhibits the problem: at least two answer groups and the associated row data.

Answer (score 4):

Use `name attribute` for radio buttons as shown in below code and your radio buttons should be in form. 
Eg: name="gender"

```
<form action="post">
    <div>
        <div class="label">Gender <span class="required">*</span></div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" required name="gender" v-model="gender" value="F">F
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" required name="gender" v-model="gender" value="M">M
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

radio button works on name basis. and your `name` seems to be the same for a group and different for different answer groups.

Comment: no name for each radio button group is dufferent. The name for each id the qestion id of the current row. Question id is different fo every row

Comment: do I need to give the same name for all radio button groups? Would'nt that make it one radio button group?

Comment: no. elements  one group needs to ahave the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Vue tries to render elements as efficiently as possible, often re-using them instead of rendering from scratch.

This isn’t always desirable, so Vue offers a way for you to say, “elements are completely separate - don’t re-use them.” To do this, add a key attribute with unique values.

Read here for more infor: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key

Comment: Just tried this. Doesn't solve the problem of radio buttons not correctly grouping in vue2, despite all groups having a different group name.